# Nodejs: wrong callback order

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, websocket

I have 3 nodejs services that exchange messages using web sockets.

The first service sends the events to the second one through web-sockets. The second service is in charge to elaborate the events and save them on a mongodb database, once that an event has been saved on the database, the second service sends the elaborated event to the third service (the gui) always using web sockets.

This is the code of the second service that receives the events from the first one:

```
this.socketClient.on('NEW_EVENT', (event: MyEvent) => {
 winston.info(`[newEvent] New Event received: %s`, event.type);
 console.log('0__', event.payload);

 // Search for the right class that can handle the specific event
 for (const handler of this.handlers) {
   if (handler.isApplicable(event.type)) {
       // Handler found
       handler.handle(event).then((handledEvent) => {
          console.log('1__', handledEvent);  
          // Send the handled event to the gui
          this.webSockerService.publishNewEvent(event.type, handledEvent);
       });
       return;
  }
 }
});
```

This is the code of the Handler that is in charge to handle one specific event (in this case it just call the right service to handle the event):

```
public async handle(event: Event): Promise<Component> {
  winston.info('[ComponentHandler:handle]');
  return this.componentService
               .componentStatusChanged(event.header.sender, event.header.senderType, event.payload);
}
```

This is the code of my componentService class (in this specific case it just uses the right repository that is in charge to save the event on the database)

```
public async componentStatusChanged(componentId: string, componentType: ComponentType, componentStatus: ComponentStatus): Promise<any> {
  return this.componentRepository
                   .componentStatusChanged(componentId, componentType, componentStatus);
}
```

And this is the code of my componentRepository:

```
public async componentStatusChanged(componentId: string, componentType: ComponentType, componentStatus: ComponentStatus): Promise<Component> {
  winston.info('[ComponentRepository::componentStatusChanged] Component %s newStatus %s', componentId, componentStatus);

  try {
    await this.fetch({ name: componentId });
    return this.update(componentId, { status: componentStatus });
  } catch (ex) {
    // Component not exists
    const newComponent: Component = {
                name: componentId,
                type: componentType,
                status: componentStatus,
                updatedAt: new Date().getTime()
     };
     return this.newComponent(newComponent);
  }
}

public async update(componentId: string, newValues: any): Promise<Component> {
  winston.info('[ComponentRepository::update] Updating component %s. New Values: %j', componentId, newValues);
  await this.component.get().update({ name: componentId }, newValues);
  return this.fetch({ name: componentId });
}

public async newComponent(component: Component): Promise<Component> {
  winston.info('[ComponentRepository::newComponent] Creating Component %j', component);
  return this.component.get().create(component);
}

public async fetch(filter: any): Promise<Component> {
  winston.info('[ComponentRepository::fetch] component %j', filter);
  return this.component.get().findOne(filter);
}
```

the problem is that the second service receives the events in the right order, but it forward them to the gui in the wrong one, following some logs:

Events payload received by the second component: STARTED --> ANALYZING --> LISTENING --> ANALYZING --> LISTENING --> ANALYZING --> LISTENING .....

As you can see in the logs, the order of the events printed by `console.log('0__...)` are not the same of the events printed by `console.log('1___....)`

```
info: [newEvent] New Event received: STATUS
0___ STARTED
info: [ComponentHandler:handle]
info: [ComponentRepository::componentStatusChanged] Component auth.srv newStatus STARTED
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
info: [newEvent] New Event received: STATUS
0___ ANALYZING
info: [ComponentHandler:handle]
info: [ComponentRepository::componentStatusChanged] Component auth.srv newStatus ANALYZING
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
info: [newEvent] New Event received: STATUS
0___ LISTENING
info: [ComponentHandler:handle]
info: [ComponentRepository::componentStatusChanged] Component auth.srv newStatus LISTENING
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
info: [ComponentRepository::update] Updating component auth.srv. New Values: {"status":"ANALYZING"}
info: [ComponentRepository::update] Updating component auth.srv. New Values: {"status":"STARTED"}
info: [ComponentRepository::update] Updating component auth.srv. New Values: {"status":"LISTENING"}
info: [newEvent] New Event received: STATUS
0___ ANALYZING
info: [ComponentHandler:handle]
info: [ComponentRepository::componentStatusChanged] Component auth.srv newStatus ANALYZING
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
info: [newEvent] New Event received: STATUS
0___ LISTENING
info: [ComponentHandler:handle]
info: [ComponentRepository::componentStatusChanged] Component auth.srv newStatus LISTENING
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
info: [newEvent] New Event received: STATUS
0___ ANALYZING
info: [ComponentHandler:handle]
info: [ComponentRepository::componentStatusChanged] Component auth.srv newStatus ANALYZING
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
info: [newEvent] New Event received: STATUS
0___ LISTENING
info: [ComponentHandler:handle]
info: [ComponentRepository::componentStatusChanged] Component auth.srv newStatus LISTENING
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
info: [newEvent] New Event received: STATUS
0___ ANALYZING
info: [ComponentHandler:handle]
info: [ComponentRepository::componentStatusChanged] Component auth.srv newStatus ANALYZING
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
info: [newEvent] New Event received: STATUS
0___ LISTENING
info: [ComponentHandler:handle]
info: [ComponentRepository::componentStatusChanged] Component auth.srv newStatus LISTENING
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
info: [newEvent] New Event received: STATUS
0___ ANALYZING
info: [ComponentHandler:handle]
info: [ComponentRepository::componentStatusChanged] Component auth.srv newStatus ANALYZING
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
info: [newEvent] New Event received: STATUS
0___ LISTENING
info: [ComponentHandler:handle]
info: [ComponentRepository::componentStatusChanged] Component auth.srv newStatus LISTENING
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
info: [newEvent] New Event received: STATUS
0___ ANALYZING
info: [ComponentHandler:handle]
info: [ComponentRepository::componentStatusChanged] Component auth.srv newStatus ANALYZING
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
info: [newEvent] New Event received: STATUS
0___ LISTENING
info: [ComponentHandler:handle]
info: [ComponentRepository::componentStatusChanged] Component auth.srv newStatus LISTENING
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
info: [newEvent] New Event received: STATUS
0___ ANALYZING
info: [ComponentHandler:handle]
info: [ComponentRepository::componentStatusChanged] Component auth.srv newStatus ANALYZING
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
info: [ComponentRepository::update] Updating component auth.srv. New Values: {"status":"ANALYZING"}
info: [ComponentRepository::update] Updating component auth.srv. New Values: {"status":"LISTENING"}
info: [ComponentRepository::update] Updating component auth.srv. New Values: {"status":"LISTENING"}
info: [newEvent] New Event received: STATUS
0___ LISTENING
info: [ComponentHandler:handle]
info: [ComponentRepository::componentStatusChanged] Component auth.srv newStatus LISTENING
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
info: [newEvent] New Event received: STATUS
0___ ANALYZING
info: [ComponentHandler:handle]
info: [ComponentRepository::componentStatusChanged] Component auth.srv newStatus ANALYZING
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
info: [newEvent] New Event received: STATUS
0___ LISTENING
info: [ComponentHandler:handle]
info: [ComponentRepository::componentStatusChanged] Component auth.srv newStatus LISTENING
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
info: [ComponentRepository::update] Updating component auth.srv. New Values: {"status":"LISTENING"}
info: [ComponentRepository::update] Updating component auth.srv. New Values: {"status":"ANALYZING"}
info: [ComponentRepository::update] Updating component auth.srv. New Values: {"status":"LISTENING"}
info: [ComponentRepository::update] Updating component auth.srv. New Values: {"status":"ANALYZING"}
info: [ComponentRepository::update] Updating component auth.srv. New Values: {"status":"ANALYZING"}
info: [ComponentRepository::update] Updating component auth.srv. New Values: {"status":"ANALYZING"}
info: [ComponentRepository::update] Updating component auth.srv. New Values: {"status":"LISTENING"}
info: [ComponentRepository::update] Updating component auth.srv. New Values: {"status":"ANALYZING"}
1____ { _id: 5af470ae8278f6320b3a00f3,
  name: 'auth.srv',
  type: 'AUTH_SERVICE',
  status: 'LISTENING',
  updatedAt: 1525969070608,
  __v: 0 }
info: [WebSocketService::publishNewEvent] type: STATUS LISTENING
1____ { _id: 5af470ae8278f6320b3a00f3,
  name: 'auth.srv',
  type: 'AUTH_SERVICE',
  status: 'LISTENING',
  updatedAt: 1525969070608,
  __v: 0 }
info: [WebSocketService::publishNewEvent] type: STATUS LISTENING
1____ { _id: 5af470ae8278f6320b3a00f3,
  name: 'auth.srv',
  type: 'AUTH_SERVICE',
  status: 'LISTENING',
  updatedAt: 1525969070608,
  __v: 0 }
info: [WebSocketService::publishNewEvent] type: STATUS LISTENING
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
info: [ComponentRepository::update] Updating component auth.srv. New Values: {"status":"ANALYZING"}
info: [ComponentRepository::update] Updating component auth.srv. New Values: {"status":"LISTENING"}
info: [ComponentRepository::update] Updating component auth.srv. New Values: {"status":"LISTENING"}
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
1____ { _id: 5af470ae8278f6320b3a00f3,
  name: 'auth.srv',
  type: 'AUTH_SERVICE',
  status: 'ANALYZING',
  updatedAt: 1525969070608,
  __v: 0 }
info: [WebSocketService::publishNewEvent] type: STATUS ANALYZING
1____ { _id: 5af470ae8278f6320b3a00f3,
  name: 'auth.srv',
  type: 'AUTH_SERVICE',
  status: 'ANALYZING',
  updatedAt: 1525969070608,
  __v: 0 }
info: [WebSocketService::publishNewEvent] type: STATUS ANALYZING
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
1____ { _id: 5af470ae8278f6320b3a00f3,
  name: 'auth.srv',
  type: 'AUTH_SERVICE',
  status: 'ANALYZING',
  updatedAt: 1525969070608,
  __v: 0 }
info: [WebSocketService::publishNewEvent] type: STATUS ANALYZING
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
info: [ComponentRepository::fetch] component {"name":"auth.srv"}
1____ { _id: 5af470ae8278f6320b3a00f3,
  name: 'auth.srv',
  type: 'AUTH_SERVICE',
  status: 'LISTENING',
  updatedAt: 1525969070608,
  __v: 0 }
info: [WebSocketService::publishNewEvent] type: STATUS LISTENING
1____ { _id: 5af470ae8278f6320b3a00f3,
  name: 'auth.srv',
  type: 'AUTH_SERVICE',
  status: 'LISTENING',
  updatedAt: 1525969070608,
  __v: 0 }
info: [WebSocketService::publishNewEvent] type: STATUS LISTENING
1____ { _id: 5af470ae8278f6320b3a00f3,
  name: 'auth.srv',
  type: 'AUTH_SERVICE',
  status: 'LISTENING',
  updatedAt: 1525969070608,
  __v: 0 }
info: [WebSocketService::publishNewEvent] type: STATUS LISTENING
1____ { _id: 5af470ae8278f6320b3a00f3,
  name: 'auth.srv',
  type: 'AUTH_SERVICE',
  status: 'LISTENING',
  updatedAt: 1525969070608,
  __v: 0 }
info: [WebSocketService::publishNewEvent] type: STATUS LISTENING
1____ { _id: 5af470ae8278f6320b3a00f3,
  name: 'auth.srv',
  type: 'AUTH_SERVICE',
  status: 'LISTENING',
  updatedAt: 1525969070608,
  __v: 0 }
info: [WebSocketService::publishNewEvent] type: STATUS LISTENING
1____ { _id: 5af470ae8278f6320b3a00f3,
  name: 'auth.srv',
  type: 'AUTH_SERVICE',
  status: 'LISTENING',
  updatedAt: 1525969070608,
  __v: 0 }
info: [WebSocketService::publishNewEvent] type: STATUS LISTENING
1____ { _id: 5af470ae8278f6320b3a00f3,
  name: 'auth.srv',
  type: 'AUTH_SERVICE',
  status: 'LISTENING',
  updatedAt: 1525969070608,
  __v: 0 }
info: [WebSocketService::publishNewEvent] type: STATUS LISTENING
1____ { _id: 5af470ae8278f6320b3a00f3,
  name: 'auth.srv',
  type: 'AUTH_SERVICE',
  status: 'LISTENING',
  updatedAt: 1525969070608,
  __v: 0 }
info: [WebSocketService::publishNewEvent] type: STATUS LISTENING
1____ { _id: 5af470ae8278f6320b3a00f3,
  name: 'auth.srv',
  type: 'AUTH_SERVICE',
  status: 'LISTENING',
  updatedAt: 1525969070608,
  __v: 0 }
info: [WebSocketService::publishNewEvent] type: STATUS LISTENING
1____ { _id: 5af470ae8278f6320b3a00f3,
  name: 'auth.srv',
  type: 'AUTH_SERVICE',
  status: 'LISTENING',
  updatedAt: 1525969070608,
  __v: 0 }
info: [WebSocketService::publishNewEvent] type: STATUS LISTENING
1____ { _id: 5af470ae8278f6320b3a00f3,
  name: 'auth.srv',
  type: 'AUTH_SERVICE',
  status: 'LISTENING',
  updatedAt: 1525969070608,
  __v: 0 }
info: [WebSocketService::publishNewEvent] type: STATUS LISTENING'
```

**EDIT**

It seems some sort of race condition when I use the WebSockets. I tried to test my components separately and there is no problem. As soon as I use the websockets and I publish the events fast and repeatedly then something happens on the callback stack.
What can I do to process the events in the right order? The problem seems to be when I try to do the I/O operation on mongodb.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem creating a queue of events that is processed separately.

If you have a better solution please post it here.

```
constructor() {
 setInterval(async () => {
   if (this.newEvents.length > 0) {
     await this.handleNewEvents();
   }
 }, 50);
}

this.socketClient.on('NEW_EVENT', (event: MyEvent) => {
   this.newEvents.push(event);
});


private async handleNewEvents(): Promise<any> {
  const event = this.newEvents.shift();
  await this.handleEvent(event);
  if (this.newEvents.length > 0) {
     await this.handleNewEvents();
  }
}

private async handleEvent(event: Event): Promise<any> {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       for (const handler of this.handlers) {
           if (handler.isApplicable(event.type)) {
                handler.handle(event).then((handledEvent) => {
                  this.webSockerService.publishNewEvent(event.type, handledEvent);
                      resolve();
                  });
                  return;
               }
            }
        winston.error('Handler not found for %s ', event.type);
           reject();
        });
    }
}
```